# PHP Executing Program With Variables

Tags: php, terminal

I am trying to run a script that saves a derived number using PHP. I've confirmed that this script works manually from the debian terminal when I execute this command, it saves a file with my number and echos

> "file saved"

```
./number-code-gen "12345678-1234-123456"
```

I've confirmed that the script works to an extent by running it without parameters using this from PHP:

```
$output = exec("./number-code-gen", $output2);
print_r($output2);
```

It echos back:

> "No Arguments. Please enter a number."

I've tried all of the following with and without quotes around the argument (works either way in terminal)

```
exec('./nfz_core "12345678-12345678-12345678"', $output2);
print_r($output2);

$output = shell_exec('./nfz_core "12345678-12345678-12345678"');
echo $output;

passthru('./number-code-gen 12345678-1234-123456',$rtn);
echo $rtn;
```

I don't get echos or errors for either of these, and my file isn't generated. Is there a specific thing I'm missing here?

Basically, I just want to run `./number-code-gen 12345678-1234-123456` from PHP, but it isn't working. **I am running Debian and PHP version: 5.6.33**

Comment: could be a permission issue

Comment: Have you tried `$output = exec('./number-code-gen "12345678-12345678-12345678"');` ?

Comment: "isn't working"... What output when passing the argument? Does the `number-code-gen` script error out? And has nothing else really changed (location, etc) between it worked command line, but not PHP?

Comment: Also, worth mentioning [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)?

Comment: Thanks @nogad. I guess the program was running under a different permission set than my terminal. The execute wasn't enough permissions on its own. Write ended up fixing.